# thread-unsafe pseudorandom number generator

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm new to C and multithreading programming, and I was reading a book which talks about thread-unsafe function as:

> A pseudorandom number generator is a simple example of this class of thread-unsafe functions. Consider the pseudorandom number generator:

```
unsigned next_seed = 1;

/* rand - return pseudorandom integer in the range 0..32767 */
unsigned rand(void)
{
    next_seed = next_seed*1103515245 + 12543;
    return (unsigned)(next_seed>>16) % 32768;
}

/* srand - set the initial seed for rand() */
void srand(unsigned new_seed)
{
    next_seed = new_seed;
}
```

> The `rand` function is thread-unsafe because the result of the current invocation depends on an intermediate result from the previous iteration. When we call rand repeatedly from a single thread after seeding it with a call to `srand`, we can expect a repeatable sequence of numbers. However, this assumption no longer holds if multiple threads are calling rand. The only way to make a function such as rand thread-safe is to rewrite
> it so that it does not use any static data, relying instead on the caller to pass the state information in arguments.

I'm a little bit confused, below is my question:

Q1-we can add `sem_wait`(`P` operation) and `sem_post` (`V` operation) functions to protect `next_seed` global varaible, then we can get the same repeatable result just like using a single thread, why the author says we need to rewrite the whole function?

Q2-Since we want to generate random numbers, therefore we don't really expect a repeatable sequence of numbers, so why `rand` function is thread-unsafe even though it behaves correctly?

Comment: "we can add sem_wait and sem_post functions to protect next_seed global varaible" -- The definition of thread safety is that you don't have to use an external mechanism like a lock to make it safe to use. The function itself isn't thread safe because it's non-idempotent and relies on global state that can be mutated by multiple threads causing a race condition. Pseudorandom isn't the same as truly random. You often want to seed RNGs and get a deterministic sequence of values.

Comment: "and there is no static varable involved". By "static" the author is talking about [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration). Not static storage class that you may be thinking of. The global variable `next_seed` has static storage duration.

Comment: Consider using thread specific variables. Here you can define your global variable as "__thread unsigned int next_seed = 1" to make it global but local to each thread.

Comment: I just use a RNG that takes a state argument instead of using a global one. `srandom_r()`/`random_r()` on glibc, `arc4random_uniform()` on BSDs (Thread safe despite the lack of a state to pass), `seed48()`/`nrand48()` etc. for POSIX, etc., PCG for third-party, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since we want to generate random numbers, therefore we don't really expect a repeatable sequence of numbers

There may be some cases where "you" really don't care but there's also a lot of cases where you want to be able to create exactly the same random sequence.

Example 1:

Assume you have written a program that runs fine again and again but then suddenly crashes one day. Now you'll like to debug the crash so you rerun the program. Now it doesn't crash... and it doesn't crash the next 10.000 times but then...

How will you ever debug that if your not able to generate exactly the same random sequence?

Example 2:

Random sequences are often used (together with e.g. various coverage measurements) for testing. It can be testing of your program but it can also be testing of external things like RTL code for FPGAs/ASICs. When a test case fails, you want to be able to redo that exact same test.

Again: How will you ever debug that if your not able to generate exactly the same random sequence?

For both of the above examples what you'll do is to print/log the seed at start up so that you can later rerun using that seed and thereby get the exact same sequence.

Regarding your Q1 the answer is more or less the same. Protection by mutexes/semaphores will not help you in getting the same sequence as you can't control the sequence that the threads will get access to the function generating the random numbers.